# How can I port an Adobe Flash game to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, porting

So there's this simple game, http://www.zigzagphilosophy.com/, that I've enjoyed playing around with every once in a while for a few years. However, I recently learned it was written in Adobe Flash, meaning its unplayable on most browsers currently and will be completely unplayable in a few months. Since it's a simple game, I decided I would try to port it to JavaScript by looking at its source code. However, the file `index.swf` that makes up the game simply downloads to my computer, where it cannot be opened by any means. How would I go about opening that file and being able to read the source code in a compiled form (e.g., looking like lines of code instead of just data)?

Comment: You would probably have to use `<canvas>` and JavaScript, but I don't think there is any easy way of doing it automatically - you would have to write it from the ground up by yourself. However, you can download Adobe Flash Player Projector: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html and you will be able to play that game even after all browsers drop support for Flash Player

Comment: I'm completely fine with rewriting the game, and I'd rather do that than simply have it on Flash Projector. I'm just not sure how to even look at the source code for the .sfw file so that I even *can* port it.

Comment: @Randall Flash is compiled and as such you can't look at the source code normally. You can try a decompiler (http://www.google.com/search?q=flash%2Bdecompiler) but it wouldn't necessarily be readable. Your best bet is to either contact the author of the flash game or to try and reverse engineer it just by playing.

Comment: @Randall It is a **very** simple game and one can tell what's under its hood literally just by looking at it. What you need is an ability to compose simplest programs in **JavaScript**, a bit of 2D physics understanding and a bit of knowledge how to animate (gradually change scale and rotation over time) an object on 2D canvas per **wilkoklak** suggestion.

Comment: Here's a JavaScript/WebAssembly Flash player: http://ruffle-rs.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/builds/web-demo/

Answer (score 1):

i have very little experience with javascript, though i read through the comments on your question and as you don't mind rewriting it yourself, i can recommend an swf decompiler for you. it's called jpexs flash decompiler and is accessible [here](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/releases). pretty sure it requires java and the gui looks pretty crappy but i can tell you from personal experience that it works well.

you can extract audio, images, basically whatever's there, as well as exporting to an fla or exe file.

i'm sorry i couldn't be of any more help than this, but i hope what i've written is at least useful :)